# Функция для подсчёта количества похожих объектов в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется массив

```
[{source_id: 333},{source_id: 333},{source_id: 333},{source_id: 555},{source_id: 555}]
```

Как сделать новый, чтобы в нем было по одному уникальному элементу, а вторым параметром шло количество. Пример:

```
[{source_id: 333,value: 3},{source_id: 555,value: 2}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function t(input) {
  const counters = new Map();
  for (const element of input) {
    const counter = counters.get(element.source_id) || 0;
    counters.set(element.source_id, counter + 1);
  }
  const result = []
  for (const [tag, counter] of counters) {
    result.push({source_id: tag, value: counter});
  }
  return result;
}

result = t([{source_id: 333},{source_id: 333},{source_id: 333},{source_id: 555},{source_id: 555}])
console.log(result)
```

Объявляем структуру для счётчиков: `const counters = new Map()`; проходимся по исходному массиву, считая количество уникальных значений source_id: `for (const element of input) { ... }`; второй цикл идёт по всем счётчикам и записывает их значения в массив-результат `for (const counter of counters) { result.push(...) }`.